# How to get enabled cipher list defined in a named ssl config?

Tags: open-liberty

I have a ssl config named `MY_SSL_CFG` defined in my server.xml where I specify one cipher list. I want to refer it using `JSSEHelper.getInstance().getSSLContext("MY_SSL_CFG", Collections.emptyMap(), null)` and use in code to configure a library.
Using the lib I have the impression that ciphers used are not aligned with what is defined in server.xml. It seems to use the JVM defaults but not sure.
Any way to list, confirm or configure ciphers enabled on this context ?

Comment: Can you post your server.xml configuration?

Comment: <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
     enabledCiphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
 />